# Custom field does not save in magento 2

Tags: magento2

We have created a custom customer attributes in magento with a custom extension. In this extension, we have also created a observer with customer_save_after and update customer attributes programmatically.

```
$customerId = $this->_customersession->getCustomerId();
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
$websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->load($customerId);
$customer->setCustomAttribute('Test');
$customer->save();
```

Above code works fine on local and development server but site moved to production server, Above code stops working. To Make it work again we need to update the save process in following manner.

```
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('my_attr_code', $val);
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customer->save();
```

Can any one guide me what the possible issue which breaks execution on live but everything is working fine on development server. 
We also tried with copy of development database on local system, it also working fine. Question is codes are same, database hasn't any issue, After changing the save process, execution starts perfectly without any error.What could be possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the server's apache specs. As you said, its working properly within your local, databases are the same, everything is the same except the server. Then check the apache php.ini and compare both Local and Live. You might have some config not letting the code to run properly.